# Copy files located in multiple subfolder, using a mildmatch search

Tags: powershell, where-clause, get-childitem, copy-item

I have tried googling my problems for some time now, without a solution that suits my needs. So hopefully you can help me.

I have some subfolders that contain millions of files. I would like to search these subfolders for filenames containing *somerandomtext*.

This is what I have, but it does not copy anything to my `$Newlocation` folder.

```cs
$Include = @"
20190421
20190422
20190423
20190424
"@

$BaseFolder  = "D:\FoldersContainingFiles"
$NewLocation = "D:\FolderForCopy\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $BaseFolder -Recurse -Include * | 
    Where-Object {$Include -contains $_.BaseName } |
    Copy-Item -Destination $NewLocation
```

No error code, only no files are being moved.

Comment: Have you tried breaking it down into separate steps and debugging them individually? I mean, do you ls, ? and copy work on their own?

Comment: Yes, it looks like they work.

Comment: the `-Include *` bit is NOT needed. you should remove it since it does nothing - that is the effective default. [*grin*] ///// why don't you use `-Include $Include` in your `Get-ChildItem` call?

Answer (score 2):

Your code will only give you files that are named exactly as the example in your variable, which is:

```
20190421
20190422
20190423
20190424
```

And that is under no circumstances a valid filename.

I'm not sure what you mean by mildmatch. If you mean, that the filename of your files contains a date amongst other things, this would solve your task:

```
$Include = "20190421|20190422|20190423|20190424"
$BaseFolder  = "D:\FoldersContainingFiles"
$NewLocation = "D:\FolderForCopy\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $BaseFolder -recurse  | 
    Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match $Include }|
    Copy-Item -Destination $NewLocation
```

If your filename is exactly the same as included in your variable, you can use this regex instead:

```
$Include = "^(20190421|20190422|20190423|20190424)$"
```

The rest of the code is the same.